# Jenkins builds with gradle subprojects

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

Is there anyway I can create a two module projects in gradle, and trigger a build for each module by itself?

```
Root project 'Example' 
    Jenkinsfile
\--- Project ':SubProject'
    Jenkinsfile
```

I want that jenkins will trigger a build only in the module that has been changed.

---

**for example** :

If my `SubProject` changed, then only `SubProject` will execute it's own `Jenkinsfile`.

I looked up for this option for a very long time...

- [Build multiproject Gradle on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316712/build-multiproject-gradle-on-jenkins)
- [Using Gradle & Jenkins on large multi projects](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-gradle-jenkins-on-large-multi-projects/11712)

As you can see in the other questions, there is no any easy way to achieve that.

Is there any `Jenkins pipeline` or `plugin` that can deal with that?

Comment: If you want to trigger them after pushing code to the "subprojects" and you have just one repo have a look to git submodules https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Answer (score 3):

- It is relatively easy to only invoke the gradle tasks from a given subproject:

  - To build *Example*: `./gradlew :build`
  - To build *SubProject*: `./gradlew :SubProject:build`
  - Gradle will then only run the task graph these invocation define.
- It should be relatively easy to setup two different jobs in Jenkins, based on distinct Jenkinsfile, and each could have the custom invocation defined above.

However, the triggering of one project only will most likely be the tricky thing as they most likely live in the same source control location.

Maybe the easy fix is also to have them decoupled, using `svn:externals` or Git submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Use `excludedRegions` to exclude folders/files that would trigger a build.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/

I'm unsure about the support of JenkinsFile...